# hibernate query on supertype returns me results from subtypes, How can I return only results from supertype?

Tags: java, hibernate, polymorphism, criteria

Is it possible to make an hibernate query only on supertype ?

My supertype whom is called Conversation has its own hbm.
Conversation is the supertype of Idea & Question which also have their own hbm.

If i make a count query on my supertype Conversation, it will also return the count of Idea & Question.
How can I avoid that ?

Example :

I have

- 3 ideas
- 4 Questions
- 1 conversation

If I make a query count on ideas it will return 3
If I make a query count on Questions it will return 4
If i make a query count on Conversation it will return 3 + 4 + 1 = 8

**I want the query to only return me 1 (only conversations)**

Comment: If you query on the supertype, you will get results for the 'supertype'. If you want results only from a specific subtype, query for that subtype

Comment: No it also returns me the results for the subtype if I make a query on supertype

Comment: Ofcourse it will, maybe you can explain a little more on your question

Answer (score 1):

How about `select count(c.id) from Conversation c where c.id not in (select i.id from Ideas i) or c.id not in (select q.id from Questions q)`

Comment: Well i want to avoid plain sql and use only Criteria queries

Comment: I haven't used criteria queries so I can't state the query, but I think the above query can be converted to a criteria query. And the query is in HQL